# How to know parent table column referred in other tables

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose that i have tables A,B,C,D and so on.

Now in table A there is  a column called id_event. My database schema contains so many tables    that it is difficult for me to find out where this column id_event has been used(in other tables).

Could you provide me any query or technique which can help me to solve this problem?

Note :I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit    Production

Answer (score 2):

A quick option is to query `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` which contains all columns in your schema, as well as tables it belongs to:

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE column_name = 'ID_EVENT';
```

---

Another option: if you paid attention to what you do and created a *good* schema, you've created primary keys, foreign key constraints and stuff, then you could query `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` in order to get information you're interested in. Here's an example; now, that you know where to look for, feel free to modify this query (or write your own). The general idea is to check the `R` constraint type (referential integrity).

```
SELECT n.constraint_name,
       n.table_name,
       n.r_constraint_name,
       r.table_name referenced_table_name,
       c.column_name,
       c.table_name,
       c1.column_name
  FROM user_constraints n
       JOIN user_constraints r ON n.r_constraint_name = r.constraint_name
       JOIN user_cons_columns c ON c.constraint_name = r.constraint_name
       JOIN user_cons_columns c1 ON c1.constraint_name = n.constraint_name
 WHERE     n.constraint_type = 'R'
       AND c.column_name = 'ID_EVENT';
```

Comment: Please find the below answer which is working for me.
SELECT owner,table_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE column_name like '%COST%'
 AND OWNER in ('TPS');